# Standing waves on string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, interference, string, superposition

I am a high school student and I am a little confused about standing waves on string, My confusion is that: we know ,A standing wave is formed by the interference of reflected wave and incident wave but I am not able to imagine at what places will the constructive and destructive interference occurs at frequencies other than natural frequencies?{you can show it on string fixed at both ends}
like we know when we vibrate the string in its normal mode frequencies then at any moment in time the destructive interference will occur at the nodes, but how will these interferences look if we vibrate the string with any other frequency, I think destructive interference should also occurs at the nodes even in this case{by nodes i mean to say only fixed ends, I know it can be other points also, but i am taking about then to easily imagine the situation}

Answer (score 0):

If you consider two waves moving in opposite directions with the same frequency, amplitude, and polarization: at a point where one wave has an increasing positive displacement and the other has an equal increasing negative displacement, you get a node. If the phase of either wave is changed, the node moves. If one of the waves is a reflection from a boundary, the relative phase is determined by the nature of the boundary. With two boundaries you get multiple reflections, each of which introduces a phase shift. You end up with a jumbled pattern.  For resonance, each reflected wave must be in phase with the previous part of the same reflection.  With two fixed boundaries, that requires a node at each boundary.